# Issue with hyprledger node sdk on calling API?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

When i am upgrading and instantiating chaincode for first time and then i hit a API from node sdk then i get below error for first time only.

> "Peer localhost:7051 has rejected transaction \"1b0f72d31c2d2baa1b7fa2d5f079ba62982f67359b30a490dae901d74b8a3a1d\"
>   with code \"ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE\"","stack":"Error: Peer
>   localhost:7051 has rejected transaction
>   \"1b0f72d31c2d2baa1b7fa2d5f079ba62982f67359b30a490dae901d74b8a3a1d\"
>   with code \"ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE\"\n

Please tell me how can i resolve this issue ?

Comment: It means after you upgrade, on the first api call you get this error but after that, it works fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding `"grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms": 20000` in **connection.js** file in node sdk.

For more information visit [here](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/tutorial-grpc-settings.html)

Answer (score 0):

Its seems issue with endorsement policy, check if your transaction is endorsed by all required endorser in the network.

You must be get endorsed by all endorser to commit the transaction in peer world state.

Comment: Well that all seems to be ok. Because after first attempt all works well. It happens for the first time only